# Python socket works as a telnet connection and requires double read

Tags: python, sockets, telnet

I'm connecting to the device using telnet. Once I connected, I need to enter user name `admin`, press enter `\n` and use blank password (enter again `\n`). After the described login process I should end up with the invitation `(prompt) #`.  I'm reading from the socket after each write. The program is below:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
#Connecting using telnet
s.connect(('192.168.1.2',23))
a = s.recv(1000)
print 'a:', a
s.send('admin\n\n')
b = s.recv(1000)
print 'b:', b
c = s.recv(1000)
print 'c:', c
```

The output of the program is the following:

```
a: ��
b: �������� ��!��"��'����#��User:
c: admin

Password:
(prompt) #
```

**QUESTION:**

Why do I need to do double read to receive all the information (`print b` and  `print c`) instead of just one read (`print b`)?

Comment: `recv()` receives *up to* the specified number of bytes. You need to read in a while loop until you receive the bytes you wanted.

Comment: `print b` and `print c` is not double reading. It's writing to stdout. To receive different lines, try using a `sleep` call between recv calls.

Comment: I called it so since they represent information I get with `b = s.recv(1000)` and `c = s.recv(1000)`

Comment: Is your socket blocking or non-blocking?

Comment: I believe that it's blocking by default in Python, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using raw sockets, you can use the [telnetlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html).

Typical usage:

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "localhost"
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("ls\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()
```

This will ask for your username and password, then use the entered information to authenticate to the server as seen here:

```
tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")
```

You can read the [telnetlib documentation for python 2.x here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html).

Comment: Also, if you are using Python 3.x the code is very similar. Take a look at the Python 3.x documentation for telnetlib here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html

Comment: No problem with telnetlib, just wanted to understand why socket doesn't work as expected

Comment: @Konstantin After a few cups of coffee i'll setup a telnet server to test your code with and i'll get back to you.

Comment: @StianOK - spot the US developer:)

Comment: @StianOK - oh, sorry:)  I assumed from 'After a few cups of coffee' that you had just got up and so, most likely, US.

Comment: @MartinJames I hear you, i had been up for a few hours but was tired.

Comment: @MartinJames I totally forgot about this...however, i believe you have to use a carriage return and newline (\r\n). This very common in different protocols.